# find the total values get in a variable in php

Tags: php, count

i am doing a shopping cart.i had a variable $total.when i add 1st product of price 200 i get  $total=200 , when i add 2nd product of price 100 i get $total=200100 when i add 3rd product of price 400 i get $total=200100400 . i want to get $total=700. how to fix this problem?

```
 session_start();
           $ar20=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'price WHERE id="'.$_SESSION['y'].'"  AND prodid="'.$row['id_product'].'" ORDER BY size DESC');

            for($i=0;$i < count($ar20);$i++)
            {
                $test=$test+$ar20[$i]['price'];
            }




             $row['price'] += $test ;
 $row['total'] = $row['price'] * intval($row['quantity']);
```

if 3 products then echo the $row['total'] will get this 100200300

Comment: In php `+` does an implicit conversion to a numeric value. This might sound like a stupid question, but are you sure you're adding the numbers together in PHP an not in a Javascript code block embedded in a PHP doc?

Comment: session_start();
           $ar20=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'price WHERE id="'.$_SESSION['y'].'"  AND prodid="'.$row['id_product'].'" ORDER BY size DESC');
   
            for($i=0;$i < count($ar20);$i++)
            {
                $test=$test+$ar20[$i]['price'];
            }
    
    echo $test;
   
   
   
    $row['price'] += $test ;
 $row['total'] = $row['price'] * intval($row['quantity']);

if 3 products then echo the $row['total'] will get this 100200300

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in comments, it's messy.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` instead of `.` operator

Comment: @Hmwd So, you're doing your math in javascript, not in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Just get the value of price each time and add it in previous on like wise, the below logic may help u
say `$newprice` is a variable where u get the price..

```
$total = 0;
$total +=$newprice;
```

Comment: i tried like as you shown but no changes, i gt the same like $total=200100400

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

$records=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'price WHERE id="'.$_SESSION['y'].'"  AND prodid="'.$row['id_product'].'" ORDER BY size DESC');

$row = array();
$test = '0';

if (count($records) < 1) {
    $row['price'] = '0';
    $row['total'] = '0';
} else {
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
        $test = bcadd($test, $record['price']);
    }

    $row['price'] = bcadd($row['price'], $test);
    $row['total'] = bcmul($row['price'], $row['quantity']);
}
```

---

[PHP: bcadd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

Comment: Check the bcadd, bcmul specification for scale.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this?

`$total = '100';

$total += '300';

$total += '300';

echo $total;`

PHP is forgiving to a point, especially to the JavaScript fans: It allows you to use the + operator as concatenation if the operands are both strings. Make sure that you don't surround them in quotes, single or double, like so:

`$total = 100;

$total += 300;

$total += 300;

echo $total;`

Comment: session_start();
           $ar20=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'price WHERE id="'.$_SESSION['y'].'"  AND prodid="'.$row['id_product'].'" ORDER BY size DESC');
   
            for($i=0;$i < count($ar20);$i++)
            {
                $test=$test+$ar20[$i]['price'];
            }
    
    echo $test;
   
   
   
    $row['price'] += $test ;
 $row['total'] = $row['price'] * intval($row['quantity']);

if 3 products then echo the $row['total'] will get this 100200300

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't clear because it has no context, but this should work:

```
$test = (integer) $test;

for($i=0; $i < count($ar20); $i++)
{
    $test = $test + (integer) $ar20[$i]['price'];
}

$row['price'] = (integer) $row['price'] + (integer) $test;

$row['total'] = $row['price'] * intval($row['quantity']);
```

Comment: i tried but the result is same. i used the code inside a foreach loop

Comment: I'm finding that kind of hard to believe, honestly.